# Problems with clean URLs .htaccess - page not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, clean-urls

I'm trying to make clean urls with php and im getting some errors. Hope someone can help.

My .htaccess is as follows:

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php
# this is the initialization
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options         +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
# these are the rewrite conditions
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
# and finally, the rewrite rules
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$    /price/index.php?var1=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$   /price/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$    /price/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Actually I'm trying to make clean urls in the subfolder `price/`.

When I enter: `mydomain.com/price/param1` it works perfect and it actually redirects me to 
`mydomain.com/price/index.php?var1=param1`

But when I try to go forward with more variables is when I get the problem. When I try to access `mydomain.com/price/param1/param2` I'm not redirected and a 404 error appears.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where this .htaccess is located -- in website root folder or is it /price/.htaccess ?

Comment: The two `RewriteCond` only apply to the single rule immediately following them.

Comment: the .htacces is located in the root folder, but thats not the problem.
mootinator, what that means?

Comment: @Dan Stern: It means the way you have the .htaccess code above, if you visited `/price/var1/var2` and there were some directories hierarchically the same way as your url, then the rewrite would kick in, and you wouldn't be able to access the directories. That's why the conditions are there, `!-f` and `!-d` means, rewrite only if there doesn't exist a file or a directory at the same location with the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # This is the initialization
    # For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
    #Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # /price/var1/var2/var3
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^price/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ /price/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L,QSA]

    # /price/var1/var2
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^price/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ /price/index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L,QSA]

    # /price/var1
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^price/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ /price/index.php?var1=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```